# I cannot figure out how to read in data after I have saved it

Tags: android, file

The problem is that I’m using the write method of the FileOutputStream class.  The docs I read said this outputs a byte to the file. I cannot find a read methes in the FileOutputStream class.
But there is a read method ikn the InputStreamReader.  The problem, is that the documentation I read said this class read function returns a char, by converting the bytes to a char.  Will this change the data.  How should I read the data back in.

code that saves the file and seems to work

```
boolean Save()
{
      String FILENAME = "hello_file";
      String string = "hello world!";
      cDate mAppoitments[];   


      try {
      FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

      int i;
      mAppoitments=cDates.GetUpperDates();
      for(i=0;i<cDates.getMaxAmount();i++)
      {
          i=mAppoitments[i].getMonth();
          fos.write( i  );
          i=mAppoitments[i].getDay();
          fos.write( i  );
          i=mAppoitments[i].getYear()-1900;
          fos.write( i  );            
      }

      mAppoitments=cDates.GetLowerDates();
      for(i=0;i<cDates.getMaxAmount();i++)
      {
          i=mAppoitments[i].getMonth();
          fos.write( i  );
          i=mAppoitments[i].getDay();
          fos.write( i  );
          i=mAppoitments[i].getYear()-1900;
          fos.write( i  );            
      }       
      fos.close();
      }
      // just catch all exceptions and return false
        catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }

 return true;
  }
```

Comment: Still confused what you are trying here. Are you trying to read the file which you just saved?

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file as a stream:

```
// open the file for reading
InputStream instream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
// prepare the file for reading
InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
```

Than you can read it line by line

Comment: reading line by line will cause a big problem, because the data is not saved as text, he saves it byte by byte.

Comment: @MByD - so just skip BufferReader and UnputReader and read byte by byte from inputStream. It as just a hint to use oher more 'inteligent' stuff and probably write it line by line...

Comment: I agree, but this should be mentioned as well.

Answer (score 1):

The rule I have is to use the same type of stream for reading and writing. So if you opened a file for writing using `openFileOutput`, use `openFileInput` to open the input stream for reading. since the method `write(int)` writes one **byte** to the file, you may safely use the method `read()` to read each byte and assign it to the variable.

**BUT**, there is a big problem in your loops - you modify i inside the loop, unrelated to the indexing:

```
      i=mAppoitments[i].getMonth(); // now i might be assigned with 12
      fos.write( i  ); // you write 12
      i=mAppoitments[i].getDay(); // now you look for mAppoitments[12].getDay()
      ....
```

Use a different variable to write those value to the file, don't modify i inside the loop. For example:

```
for(i=0;i<cDates.getMaxAmount();i++)
  {
      int j;
      j=mAppoitments[i].getMonth();
      fos.write( j  );
      j=mAppoitments[i].getDay();
      fos.write( j  );
      j=mAppoitments[i].getYear()-1900;
      fos.write( j  );            
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's more comfortable for you, you can wrap the output stream in a PrinterWriter, and you can wrap the input steam reader in a BufferedReader.  Then, you could write and read Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have some issues with using `i` for an iterator and as your variable for storing what you're writing.